# oop php simple function to insert data into mysql database using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

am new to php OOP I have tried to create a function in php to insert data to database but its not working ,please help.

my function:

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array(), $values = array()) {
    $sql = " INSERT INTO{$table}($fields) VALUES($values)";
    $this->_pdo->prepare ( $sql );
    return $this->_pdo->exec ( $sql );
}
```

Comment: `$fields` is an array, and you don't implode it

Comment: @Rizier123 don't forget the `$values` as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working OOP PHP Insert function, it should be easy to understand it but if you don´t just ask.

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        $keys   = array_keys($fields);
        $values = null;
        $x      = 1;

        foreach($fields as $value) {
            $values .= "?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks men,and is there a way I can make the function to have a return statement as my function above ?

Comment: The function return true if it worked, if it didn't it return false

Comment: I have modified the function  above to:

Comment: modified to:public function insert($table, $fields = array(), $values = array()) {
  $fields = '`' . implode ( '`,`', $fields ) . '`';

  $values = "'" . implode ( "','", $values ) . "'";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ($fields) VALUES($values)";
  if ($this->_pdo->exec ( $sql )) {
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }     and am calling it :$db = Connection::getConnectionInstance ()->insert ( 'hss_email', array (
  'name',
  'email',
  'subject',
  'message'
), array (
  'moses',
  'ms@gmail.com',
  'testing',
  'message'
) );

if ($db) {
 echo 'executed';
} else {
 echo 'failed';
}